# Cocoa NSIndexSet : Multiple Indexes. How to create the index set, multiple indexes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to figure out how to create a set of indexes of lets say (1, 2, 3)
then use it in

```
- (void)selectRowIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes byExtendingSelection:(BOOL)extend
```

It's the `(NSIndexSet *)indexes` I do not know how to use / create / populate with indexes 1, 2, 3.
Should I use a class method or instance method?

I tried a whole bunch of ways but I have no idea what I'm doing ...

Answer (score 76):

If the indexes are consecutive like in your example, you can use this:

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 3)];
```

If not, create a mutable index set and add the indexes (or ranges) one by one:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
[indexSet addIndex:3];
[indexSet addIndex:5];
[indexSet addIndex:8];
```

Comment: With what you wrote, I read the docs for NSIndexSet over and over again until I understood them! I guess the hardest part is not Cocoa , it's learning the logic and subtlety of code documentation!

Comment: I think the documentation is extremely clear. What did you have problems with?

Answer (score 7):

For simple index sets which contain a single index or a group of indexes which can be represented by a range (i.e. 1,2,3), you can create them using NSIndexSet's `initWithIndex:` or `initWithIndexesInRange:` methods (or their factory method counterparts). If you want to create a more complex index set (i.e. 1,5,7,8,9), you will need to use NSMutableIndexSet so that you can add indexes and ranges after you create the object.

This code will create an index set containing the indexes 1, 2, and 3:

```
[[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1,3)];
```

See the [NSIndexSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSMutableIndexSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMutableIndexSet) class references.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3

```
let indexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: 1...3)
```

or for a single value:

```
let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: 1)
```

or for non consecutive values:

```
var indexSet = IndexSet()
indexSet.insert(1)
indexSet.insert(3)
indexSet.insert(9)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a example to delete selected index from the Local Array with the help of NSMutableIndexSet**

```
NSArray * arrSelectedSongs = [self.playListTblView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
 //Delete From Array
 NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc]init];
 for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in arrSelectedSongs)
 {
   [indexSet addIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
 [self.arrFiles removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also

```
[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1];
```